# Twilio Rails Integration for Devise and Milia

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems, twilio

Firstly sorry for a newbie question. Just started developing in rails around 15 days back. Now I have installed Milia, Devise and they handle all the work for signing up, logging in, and entering the customer data into the DB.

**What am I trying to achieve?**
I want to send an SMS to a customer, whose mobile no, we will be taking using a data entry form, whose code I have shown below.
Now once all the information is entered, and the create customer button is pressed, all the information is entered into the DB. Once the button is pressed, I want an SMS to be sent via Twilio, to the customer with a defined body.

For this, I have created a controller, an SMS.rb file and a form which has the code which should help in firing the SMS.

FORM for Entering the Information:

```
 <%= form_for [@sms, @tenant, @customer], :html => { :class => "form-horizontal customer" }, :id => 'form1' do |f| %>
  <% if @customer.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_expl" class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><%= pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this customer from being saved:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
        <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<h3 align=centre>Personal Infomation</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :date_of_birth, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :dob, :class => 'form-control datepicker' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :mobileno, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :mobileno, :class => 'form-control', :id =>"mobileno", onblur:"Calculate()" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email_Id, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :emailid, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <H3 align=centre>Address</H3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :building, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :building, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :sub_area, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :subarea, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :locality, :class => 'control-label col-md-2'%>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :locality, :class => 'form-control', :id => "locality", onblur: "Calculate()" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :pincode, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :pin, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3 align=left>Medical Information</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :blood_group, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :bg, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :diseases, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'Diabetes', checked('Diabetes'), id: 'diseases_diabetes'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_diabetes', 'Diabetes' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'Cancer', checked('Cancer'), id: 'diseases_cancer'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_cancer', 'Cancer' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'TB', checked('TB'), id: 'diseases_tb'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_tb', 'TB' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'BP', checked('BP'), id: 'diseases_tb'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_bp', 'BP' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'HIV', checked('TB'), id: 'diseases_tb'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_hiv', 'HIV' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'Brain Tumor', checked('Brain Tumor'), id: 'diseases_tb'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_brain_tumor', 'Brain Tumor' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'STD', checked('STD'), id: 'diseases_tb'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_std', 'STD' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :medicine, :class => 'control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :medicin, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :allergy, :class => 'control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :allergy, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :uid, :class => 'control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4'%>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :uid , :class => 'form-control', :id => 'uid' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
    <br>
      <%= f.hidden_field :tenant_id, value: params[:tenant_id], :class => 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                root_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

SMS.rb FILE:

```
class SMS < ActiveRecord::Base  

  def client
    Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_account_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_token
  end

  acct_sid = "ACCOUNT_SID"
  auth_token = "AUTH_TOKEN"
  twilio_no = "+16xxxxxxxxx"
  acct_sid = ENV['twilio_account_sid']
  auth_token = ENV['twilio_token']
  twilio_no = ENV['twilio_no']

  def send
    numberto = params[:mobileno]
    client.account.messages.create(
    :messaging_service_sid => Rails.application.secrets.twilio_messaging_service_sid,
    :from => "+1xxxxxxxxxx",
    :to => "#{numberto}",
    :body => "Hi. Thanks a lot for signing up with us. Your UID is: #{uid}"
    )
end
```

**The problem I am facing:**

I cannot add @sms to the form as it has [@tenant, @cusotmer] already. Adding @sms, gives me an error.

I am frantically stuck and don't know how to proceed. Can you guys help me out?

**Things to Know**
1. Using Rails 4.2.6
2. Using Ruby 2.3.3

**UPDATES**

I have updated the Form.html.erb file now.
Here it is:

```
 <%= form_for [@tenant, @customer], :html => { :class => "form-horizontal customer" }, :id => 'form1' do |f| %>
  <% if @customer.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_expl" class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><%= pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this customer from being saved:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
        <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<h3 align=centre>Personal Infomation</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :date_of_birth, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :dob, :class => 'form-control datepicker' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :mobileno, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :mobileno, :class => 'form-control', value: params[:mobile], :id =>"mobileno", onblur:"Calculate()" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email_Id, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :emailid, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <H3 align=centre>Address</H3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :building, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :building, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :sub_area, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :subarea, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :locality, :class => 'control-label col-md-2'%>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :locality, :class => 'form-control', :id => "locality", onblur: "Calculate()" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :pincode, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :pin, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3 align=left>Medical Information</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :blood_group, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :bg, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :diseases, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'Diabetes', checked('Diabetes'), id: 'diseases_diabetes'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_diabetes', 'Diabetes' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'Cancer', checked('Cancer'), id: 'diseases_cancer'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_cancer', 'Cancer' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'TB', checked('TB'), id: 'diseases_tb'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_tb', 'TB' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'BP', checked('BP'), id: 'diseases_tb'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_bp', 'BP' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'HIV', checked('TB'), id: 'diseases_tb'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_hiv', 'HIV' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'Brain Tumor', checked('Brain Tumor'), id: 'diseases_tb'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_brain_tumor', 'Brain Tumor' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
      <%= check_box_tag 'customer[diseases][]', 'STD', checked('STD'), id: 'diseases_tb'%>
      <%= label_tag 'diseases_std', 'STD' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :medicine, :class => 'control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :medicin, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :allergy, :class => 'control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :allergy, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :uid, :class => 'control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4'%>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :uid , :class => 'form-control', :id => 'uid' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
    <br>
      <%= f.hidden_field :tenant_id, value: params[:tenant_id], :class => 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                root_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have also updated the Customer.rb file:
Here it is:

```
    def format_phone_number
        self.to = "+91" + (self.to.gsub('-',''))
    end

    def client
        Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_account_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_token
      end

      acct_sid = "Axxxxxxxxxxxx"
      auth_token = "6xxxxxxxxxxx"
      twilio_no = "+1xxxxxxxxxxx"
      acct_sid = ENV['twilio_account_sid']
      auth_token = ENV['twilio_token']
      twilio_no = ENV['twilio_no']

      def send (to,body)
        client.account.messages.create(
        :messaging_service_sid => Rails.application.secrets.twilio_messaging_service_sid,
        :to => '#{mobileno}',
        :body => "Hi. Thanks a lot for signing up with us. Your UID is: #{uid}"
        )
    end
```

Instead of writing in the sms.rb file, I have written the code in customer.rb and erased the sms.rb file and now it is connecting well to the Twilio API. But it takes a random number as the **to** number +66245366 and so the message sending fails. I don't know why this is happening.

**Latest Updated**

**Customer.rb**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save do
        self.diseases.gsub!(/[\[\]\"]/,"") if attribute_present?("diseases")
    end

      belongs_to :tenant
      validates_uniqueness_of :mobileno

    def self.by_plan_and_tenant(tenant_id)
        tenant = Tenant.find(tenant_id)
        if tenant.plan == 'free'
            tenant.customers
        else
            tenant.customers
        end
    end

    def client
        Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_account_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_token
      end

      acct_sid = "Axxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      auth_token = "6cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      twilio_no = "+16xxxxxxxxx"
      acct_sid = ENV['twilio_account_sid']
      auth_token = ENV['twilio_token']
      twilio_no = ENV['twilio_no']

      def send (to, body)
        client.account.messages.create(
        :messaging_service_sid => Rails.application.secrets.twilio_messaging_service_sid,
        :from => "+1xxxxxxxxx1",
        :to => '#{mobileno}',
        :body => "Hi. Thanks a lot for signing up with us. Your UID is: #{uid}"
        )
    end
end
```

Comment: What does your controller do here? Does the `SMS` class actually save data to the database?

Comment: Hi, It doesn't save SMS class to the DB. It will take the phone number from the form, while the form is being submitted and will then send an SMS to that number.

Comment: When you save the form, does the `mobileno` field get saved to the `Customer` object correctly? It looks like you want to use the `format_phone_number` field too, but you're using that on the `to` field, so I'm not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: Hi, The format_phone_number only formats the phone number and makes sure that the dashes and spaces are removed with any extra characters. The only problem I am facing is the SMS not being sent. Yes, the mobile gets saved in the customer field without any problem.

Comment: I understand that the problem is that the SMS isn't sending, however you said that the "To" number is appearing as a weird number. I'm trying to work out how you get from entering a real number into your form and it turning into the wrong number. `format_phone_number` could have been part of that. Is `mobileno` saved as a string in your DB? If you log `mobileno` in the `send` function before you create the message, do you see the right number?

Comment: I have updated the code now, it is in customer.rb as before, but the error shown is: The 'To' number phone_number is not a valid phone number.
I am trying to pass the mobileno which is perfectly being saved in the db to the phone_number class. But I think, it isn't passing the db value to the phone_number class

Comment: If I directly enter the mobile number, in the to the field, the SMS is sent without any problem. It's just that the SMS are sent continuously without the code being stopped. I think it goes in a loop. Please read the previous comment too.

Comment: Added the code in the update. Please have a look.

Comment: So, SMS messages are sending? But now you're sending too many? When is the `send` method of `Customer` called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140159/discussion-between-tanay-and-philnash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

After a [long chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140159/discussion-between-tanay-and-philnash) we changed the method name to send SMS messages from `send` (which is an important method for objects in Ruby) to `send_sms`.

Then we ensured the number had the right international code.

```
def send_sms()
  client.account.messages.create(
    :messaging_service_sid => Rails.application.secrets.twilio_messaging_service_sid,
    :from => "+16312010201",
    :to => "#+91{mobileno}",
    :body => "Hi. Thanks a lot for signing up with us. Your UID is: #{uid}"
  )
end
```

We then updated the Customers controller create action to send the SMS when the customer was successfully created:

```
def create
  @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @customer.save
      format.html {
        @customer.send_sms
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Customer data was successfully created.'
      }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

So things work now.